Emacs intermittently experiences slowdowns
For the last couple of weeks, emacs in my machine have become intermittently slow. It works fine, then suddenly (I have yet to find any triggering keystroke) it slows down for about fifteen seconds. In that period, it becomes completely unresponsive. Any character typed in that period appears after the slow-down period.
Here is the profiler report. But I don't know how to proceed further.
I am using an Ubuntu machine. I use emacs mostly to edit my LaTeX files.


Do M-x toggle-debug-on-quit and do C-g when you are in the middle of the slowdown. That should give you a backtrace. Do it again a few times to see if it is reliably reproducible. Does the backtrace look similar? Is the same function at the top of the stack? If so, post the backtrace here. Profiler reports are not particularly informative in your case: they accumulate information over a possibly long period of time (between the time that you enable and the time that you stop) so they don't accurately reflect out-of-the-ordinary events in the last few seconds.

@NickD, Thanks, I will do that, at the first available opportunity.

You haven't messed with the garbage collection settings, have you?  (I've seen people set the thresholds to crazy-high numbers, which inevitably means it'll take a really long time when it happens).

@phils, I don't remember changing anything explicitly. How do I check whether I have done or not done anything you suspect?

@phils, gc-cons-threshold value is 800000. gc-cons-percentage value is 0.1

Ok, nothing to do with that, then.  Those are standard values.

Seeing as there's nothing suspicious in the report, I would presume the reason is that some command being called synchronously, and Emacs just waits for it exit. If that happens, you wouldn't see it on the graph because that's a "latency" as opposed to cpu load. I suggest you executing in the background sudo bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_exec*{ printf("pid: %d, comm: %s, args: ", pid, comm); join(args->argv); }' and waiting for the problem. The command will print every process launched in the system, so if a program was started, you should see it.
